# CSS Sibling Selector inconsistency when dealing with input fields

Tags: html, css

I've got the following html/css which is intended to change a sibling element to red if the input element before it has a class of "invalid", My question is what would explain this sibling selector behavior when the first element is an input field?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style tyle="text/css">
    div.required_text
    {
      color:#008000;
      display:inline;
    }
    input.invalid + div.required_text
    {
      color:#800000;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><input type="text" class=""><div class="required_text">Required</div></p>
    <p><input type="text" class=""><div class="required_text">Required</div></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="invalid"><div class="required_text">Required</div></p>
  </body>
</html
```

If I change my HTML to use a div, this slector is fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style tyle="text/css">
    div.required_text
    {
      color:#008000;
      display:inline;
    }
    div.invalid + div.required_text
    {
      color:#800000;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><div class="">[mock form element]</div><div class="required_text">Required</div></p>
    <p><div class="">[mock form element]</div><div class="required_text">Required</div></p>
    <p><div class="invalid">[mock form element]</div><div class="required_text">Required</div></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Ok so it seems there are extra paragraph tags being added to the rendered output when each line is wrapped with paragraph tags which is breaking the sibling selection, what causes this?

Comment: Here is a fiddle so that people can see. Notice how in the first trio everything is green while in the second the last one is red. http://jsfiddle.net/KnpA9/

Comment: I've just discovered by warpping the lines with input fields there are extra paragraph tags being added http://jsfiddle.net/KnpA9/1/

Comment: You should not put <div> tags inside <p> tags >> http://www.google.com/search?q=div+inside+p

Comment: Evidently so, which explains my problem.

Comment: My answer addresses your edit with examples, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this markup instead

```
<div><input type="text" class=""><span class="required_text">Required</span></div>
```

<strike>You should not put block elements into inline elements.</strike>

from the DTD

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
```

says that paragraphs can only contain 0 or more inline elements

Comment: Where is a block element being placed into an inline element? The `input` element is an empty inline element, it can't contain any children.

Comment: i guess  p is just a special case

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't nest `<div>` elements in `<p>` elements. The spec simply forbids it that way ([here's a link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html)). An opening `<div>` tag will implicitly close a preceding opening `<p>` tag if it is there, so essentially the DOM structure for your first markup looks like this:

```
p
  input
div
p
  input
div
p
  input.invalid
div
```

Rather than this:

```
p
  input
  div.required_text
p
  input
  div.required_text
p
  input.invalid
  div.required_text
```

And the DOM structure constructed by your second markup looks like this:

```
p
div
div.required_text
p
div
div.required_text
p
div.invalid
div.required_text
```

Rather than this:

```
p
  div
  div.required_text
p
  div
  div.required_text
p
  div.invalid
  div.required_text
```

Which makes all your `<div>`s siblings of their preceding `<p>`s, rather than children.